# Is it possible to draw TeeChart PieSeries titles on the pies instead of the legend?

Tags: delphi, teechart

I have a `DBChart` with four `PieSeries` on it. Each chart has multiple slices, and is multicolored. I'd like to have the title of each series written either on it or beneath it, instead of the legend. Is there any easy way to accomplish this? I'm using TeeChart Standard v2011.03.32815 VCL

Comment: Seems there is no easy way for that in TChart. My suggestion would be to have 4 TDBCharts nicley alligned with only one PieSeries in each.

Comment: The official support people for TeeChart monitor this site, and may have a better answer, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pro version includes the Annotation tool that would be useful here.

With the Standard version, you could just have 4 TDBCharts as mentioned in a comment above, or you could also draw manually your texts on the canvas. Ie:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to 3 do
    with Chart1.AddSeries(TPieSeries) as TPieSeries do
    begin
      FillSampleValues;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Chart1AfterDraw(Sender: TObject);
var i, tmpX, tmpY: Integer;
    tmpStr1, tmpStr2: string;
begin
  tmpStr1:='My Pie nº';

  for i:=0 to Chart1.SeriesCount-1 do
  begin
    tmpStr2:=tmpStr1+IntToStr(i+1);
    with (Chart1[i] as TPieSeries), Chart1.Canvas do
    begin
      tmpX:=CircleXCenter-(TextWidth(tmpStr2) div 2);
      if (i<2) then
        tmpY:=CircleRect.Top-20
      else
        tmpY:=CircleRect.Bottom+10;

      TextOut(tmpX, tmpY, tmpStr2);
    end;
  end;
end;
```